# Script to format phone numbers

Tags: bash, scripts

Noob here,
I need help with a shell script. I need to remove hyphens and add opening parenthesizes around the area code. I am able to show just the area code by adding echo {phone:0:3} to the script. Any help is much appreciated.

Write a script (called phone_num.sh) that prompts users for a phone number is this format xxx-xxx-xxxx

•   convert it to (xxx) xxx-xxx

•   convert it to xxxxxxxxx

Example  If the input is 123-123-1234, your code would display

(123) 123-1234

1231231234

```
echo "Please enter phone number in the following format xxx-xxx-xxxx:"
read phone
echo ${phone:0:3}
```

This will give me the area code, which I'm not looking for. I need hyphens removed and parenthesizes added to the area code.

Comment: Has your instructor placed any limits on what techniques you use to solve this problem?

Comment: We've just been scratching the surface with variables. We are trying to use substring patterns and search and replace.....thanks for the help

Comment: If you got to `${phone:0:3}`, `${phone:3:3}` and `${phone:6}` should follow quickly enough.

Comment: -muru 3 I tried your suggestion but it only eliminates digits from the phone number. I'm trying to remove the hyphens and create parenthesizes around the area code.

Comment: But you do know how to `echo`. Do you know you can `echo "(${phone:0:3}) ${phone:4}"`?

Comment: Yes, I am using echo to produce the results when I run the script....thanks for help

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these variable assignments might help you out:

```
$ phonedash=123-123-1234

$ phonenodash="${phonedash//-}"

$ phone=$phonenodash

$ echo $phone
1231231234

$ echo "(${phone:0:3}) ${phone:3:3}-${phone:6:4}"
(123) 123-1234

$ new_phone=$(echo "(${phone:0:3}) ${phone:3:3}-${phone:6:4}")

$ echo $new_phone 
(123) 123-1234
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I had figured out how to put the parenthesizes but was having trouble getting all the hyphens deleted...didn't realize I needed another forward slash. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @DSH72 You're very welcome!  Glad I could help!  =)

Answer (score 0):

Bash + printf

```
$ VAR="123-456-7890"; printf "( %s ) %s - %s \n %s%s%s\n" ${VAR:0:3} ${VAR:4:3} ${VAR:8:4} ${VAR:0:3} ${VAR:4:3} ${VAR:8:4}
( 123 ) 456 - 7890 
 1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
$ phone="123-456-7890"
$ plainPhone=$(echo $phone | sed "s/-//g")
$ formatedPhone1=$(echo $phone | sed "s/\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)/(\1) \2 - \3/")
$ formatedPhone2=$(echo $plainPhone | sed "s/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]*\)/(\1) \2 - \3/")
$
$ echo $plainPhone 
1234567890
$ echo $formatedPhone1 
(123) 456 - 7890
$ echo $formatedPhone2 
(123) 456 - 7890
```